# Anylogic: traffic condition

Tags: gis, traffic, anylogic, logistics

Is there a way we can add a traffic condition on a route?

For example

Speed is 40 miles from 8 - 5pm
It goes upto 60 miles after 5pm.

Current Anylogic can import a GIS map but it seems like to provide a road network itself.

Answer (score 0):

yes there is a way.

1. I would suggest looking into Anylogic Agents and how they work.
   take a look here: [anylogic agent doc](https://help.anylogic.com/topic/com.xj.anylogic.help/html/agentbased/Agent_DB.html)
2. when you have created and agent for your cars, trucks etc., you'll need a statechart to manage the different states of your model: [Anylogic statechart doc](https://help.anylogic.com/topic/com.xj.anylogic.help/html/discrete/Statecharts.html?resultof=%22%73%74%61%74%65%63%68%61%72%74%22%20)
3. In the statechart you can create a function that monitor the time or whatever parameter you want. when the condition is true you proceed to the relevant state eg. rush hour, noon or whatever you need.
4. when you are in that state you can add your code to change to the speed you want

Comment: could you mark the question as "answered" to close the question